# Auto submit selection upon onChange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a selection form which supposed to updated database on change by using jQuery, but no effect at all, can someone help with this?

```
<SELECT name='status' id='status'>
<option value="<?php echo $status ?>"><?php echo $status ?></option>
<option value="Inquiry">Inquiry</option>
<option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
<option value="Departured">Departured</option>
<option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="gp_name" id="gp_name" value="<?php echo $gp_name;?>" />
<div id="autosavenotify"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').live('change',function () {
    var statusVal = $(this).val();
    var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
    alert(statusVal);
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "lotus_savestatus.php",
             data: {statusType : statusVal, gp_name:gp_name},
             success: function(msg) {
                 $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
             }
  })
});
});
</script>
```

statussave.php

```
<?php
$gp_name=$_POST['gp_name'];
$st=$_POST['statusType'];
$qry =" UPDATE lotus_gp SET `status`=$st where gp_name='".$_POST["gp_name"]."'";
$done = mysql_query($qry);
if($done)
{
echo "Saved Successfully";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's loud and clear** *!*

**[jQuery .live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/)**

*Note: This API has been removed in jQuery 1.9; please use on() instead.*

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).live is not a function TypeError:
>   $(...).live is not a function

Instead of `.live()` use `.on()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
      var statusVal = $(this).val();
      var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
      alert(statusVal);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lotus_savestatus.php",
        data: {
          statusType: statusVal,
          gp_name: gp_name
        },
        success: function(msg) {
          $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='status' id='status'>
  <option value="<?php echo $status ?>">
    <?php echo $status ?>
  </option>
  <option value="Inquiry">Inquiry</option>
  <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
  <option value="Departured">Departured</option>
  <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="gp_name" id="gp_name" value="<?php echo $gp_name;?>" />
<div id="autosavenotify"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but database hasn't updated, it seems lotus_savestatus.php didn't get result, any recommendation?

Comment: @HenrikKwok after `ajax` call, Is there any error in browser console? also check network tab, see what is the status of your php file and what is returned?

Comment: @HenrikKwok it means you didn't include jquery library

Comment: the problem should in the script tab

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
      var statusVal = $(this).val();
      var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
      alert(statusVal);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lotus_savestatus.php",
        data: {
          statusType: statusVal,
          gp_name: gp_name
        },
        success: function(msg) {
          $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
        }
      })
    });
  });
</script>

Comment: sorry, because I have open a new test page for this code and forgot to include jquery library, I have paste it in the page now, but still no update the database, it has display "Saved Successfully", but database still not update...

Comment: @HenrikKwok I have no idea, I think you got a php or db issue, as you tagged only `jquery` , js part solved, right? so I think this question has right answer, You need create another topic for this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I realise that gp_name value hasn't send, can you take a look if "var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();" in a correct place?

Comment: @HenrikKwok good to hear. I don't see any problem except your `html` , you used echo value on this input, is this value has really value? or it's empty

Answer (score 2):

Just need to use "on" instead of "live" method in Jquery. because it has been deprecated.

```
$('select').live('change',function () {
```